# overwrite, cancel or invalidate a prerendered page

Tags: javascript, html, prefetch, prerender

In HTML you can now use prefetch, *prerender like this

```
<link rel="prerender" href="https://www.adorama.com/">
```

This prerenders the next page behind the scenes 
This is used a lot in blogs and e-commerce listing pages to pre-render the next pages..

But the problem is, What if after the prerender successfully ran, and now the user made a change in the page that alters the way the next page (the one that is already pre-rendered) behaves.

How can we **invalidate** that prerendered page, so when we view it first it will request a new page and not show the pre-rendered page.

We don't want to overwrite the link, Because we want to benefit from client or CDN caching..

*(See a nice talk about this from [Yoav Weiss - Hinting the browser](http://yoavweiss.github.io/velocity_nyc_resource_hints/#1))

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of now, is to have logic in the pre-rendered page to check for [page visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) and we can check if `visibilityState === prerender` and then add a event listener for on `visibilitychange` and on the event that `visibilityState === visible` we can check if the stored values (settings) are still the same and if not we can run the logic needed to render page correctly or simply refresh the page.....